# Issue trying to open customized link

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I got a file like index.html in a directory called foo with the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function openNewWindow(){
        window.open("openThisFakeLink"); 
        self.focus();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="blank" onClick="openNewWindow()">Click Here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

So the browser open an address like: foo/index.html

When I click the "Click Here" text, the browser opens foo/openThisFakeLink

But I need that the browser opens just: openThisFakeLink (without the rute of the directory)

How to do that?

Comment: Could you give an example of `openThisFakeLink`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link is interpreted as relative so the appropriate path is added. try `http://fakeLink/`.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open("/openThisFakeLink");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "http://" to the beginning of the link path.